# Convert string to file and then to base64

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string as `const content="<div>How do I <b>convert </b> this string to file?</div>";`
What's the correct way to convert this to a html file and have it in turn converted as base64 string in the end.
`Buffer.from(content).toString('base64')` converts just the string to base64 but not as file

Comment: Looks like the o/p of both are same
`console.log(Buffer.from(content).toString('base64'));`
// read `index.html` in base64
`console.log(fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString('base64'));`

Answer (score 1):

Use create-html

```
var fs = require('fs')
var createHTML = require('create-html')
var html = createHTML({
      title: 'example',
      body: '<div>How do I <b>convert </b> this string to file?</div>'
})
    fs.writeFile('index.html', html, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
})
  console.log(fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString('base64'));
```

for more information see this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-html

Answer (score 0):

The [Node file system API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) allows you to easily perform such actions:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const content="<div>How do I <b>convert </b> this string to file?</div>";

// write `content` to `index.html`
fs.writeFileSync('index.html', content);

// read `index.html` in base64
console.log(fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString('base64'));
```